# One character of the word is missing in some IE and mozilla Browsers?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have used font LatoBold for a div paragraph .In some IE and Mozilla browsers ,In know more 'K' is missing and there is no space between know more it is showing 'NOWMORE'.What is the problem. is this Lato Bold font issue.How to get it done.For ie7 and ie8 i am loading eot font type.

for all browsers

```
  <style>
     @font-face {
     font-family: LatoBold;
     src: url("../fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"),url('../fonts/Lato-Bold.woff') format('woff');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
    }
 </style>
```

for ie7 and ie8

```
 <style>
     @font-face {
    font-family: LatoBold;
    src:url("../fonts/Lato-Bold.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Lato-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("eot");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
   }
 </style>
 <div>
      <p>KNOW MORE</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: can we also see your css used?

Comment: On *which* versions of IE and Mozilla does this happen? Does it happen when you use Lato as hosted by Google?

Comment: No i am not using google fonts,i downloaded font files and i am using downloaded fonts only. browsers versions are mozilla 33.1.1 and ie7 and ie8

Answer (score -1):

According to a [recent Google update](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato):

> Update, August 2014: The previous version of Lato included Extended
>   Latin characters in the Latin subset. If you are experiencing
>   problems, please select the Extended Latin (latin-ext) subset to
>   render all European languages correctly. Here is an example of a
>   complete link tag that selects these subsets:

```
<link
href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question? “K” isn’t an “Extended Latin” character.